# How do I render one component right on top of another?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux

Imagine there is a list being rendered on clicking search with some info in it. when i click on one of the search results another component like a card needs to be rendered on top of the results which is more detailed. I want the component to be floating on top of the other while they both are still being rendered. How would i achieve something like this ?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS? Absolutely position one to the other's relative position? Can you shared your attempt?

Comment: Implementation of something like this definitely needs us to review your existing code or whatever you have so far

Comment: Don't use a different component placed ontop of it. You're going to have to deal with scroll position'd elements. Instead just pass an active prop to the item you clicked. Render more details there / change css classes to style it differently. You can make an element look like its ontop of the page with just some custom css. If you need help with that i'd be happy to :)